# Solr filter query doesn't return result for _s but returns for _t

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm new to solr, we are using solrj and v4.10. when we try to filter query(fq) for the field item_supp_s it doesnt return results, but when I query using qf desc_ngram desc_en^10 des_txt^30 and q as desc_en: test & test Pte. Ltd.
we are escaping all the special characters. and I can see item_supp_s is returned in the response.

But when I add the fq item_supp_name_s :(test & test Pte. Ltd) it returns 0 response and if i change it to _t it returns the results.

in data-config.xml we have the field colum="supp" name="item_supp_s"
in schema.xml we have the field name = "item_supp_t" type = "text_general"
and copy field we have copied item_supp_s to desc_en, _ngram, _txt, _t, _e , _si.

I'm not sure about the field and copy field is causing the issue. kindly advice

Comment: So what is the content of the field, and what is your actual query? `_s` is the default prefix for `string` fields and will only return _exact_ hits - where the query and the indexed content is _identical_.

Comment: As Mats mentioned, typically `_txt` fields are "text" fields, and `_s` fields are string fields. In Solr these two field types are very different among each other. String fields are stored as-is and searches will only find exact matches (including spaces, punctuation, and case sensitive.) On the other hand text fields are tokenized and run through several transformation to allow for more flexible search matches. See here for more information: https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/master/tutorial.md#fields-in-our-schema

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh Thanks for the help. I was searching with escaped string. when searched using the exact phrase it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @HectorCorrea thanks for the detailed explanation.